# Detect that EditText's Input is Number and do not allow the user type other sort of characters

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

Hi there i was developing an app then i got into how can my app detect the input of edit text.
For example after putting something in edittext , i want only Digit inputs not characters.

```
public class percentInputActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText correctInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCorrect);
    Button calButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calButton);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_percent_input);



    }}
```

Comment: You can add android:inputType="number" as an XML attribute.

Comment: Or you can add a `TextWatcher` and discard the input if it is not a number by regex matching. The regex in you case should be [0-9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the design panel of your window, choose your EditText and search for **inputType** attribute, from there you can choose exactly what you are expecting to receive, in your case you should choose number.

[image: inputType]

feel free also to check the other options.